# Installing modules from requirements.txt on multiple machines and on AWS, Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gdal, requirements.txt

I am working with Python 3.6 and I am having a project for which I created requirements.txt file using pipreqs. But when I run pip install -r requirements.txt, the build fails because a specific library GDAL can be installed only using those three commands:

```
conda create -n gdal_test python=3.5
activate gdal_test
conda install gdal
```

What is the best way to deal with this if I want everyone to be able to install things without issues on different local machines and different EC2 instances on AWS and using microservices? Obviously only running requirements file is not going to work. Is Docker a solution? If so, how? Do I also need a setup.py file? Thanks.